# Pandas maximum difference of values with day-to-day intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Continuation of previous [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69279835/calculate-maximum-difference-of-rolling-interval-of-n-columns)

```
df

                    Timestamp  Spot DK1  Spot DK2  Ubalance DK1  Ubalance DK2
0   2020-01-01T00:00:00+01:00     33.42     33.42         34.00         34.00
1   2020-01-01T01:00:00+01:00     31.77     31.77         34.00         34.00
2   2020-01-01T02:00:00+01:00     31.57     31.57         34.00         34.00
3   2020-01-01T03:00:00+01:00     31.28     31.28         34.00         34.00
4   2020-01-01T04:00:00+01:00     30.85     30.85         26.00         26.00
5   2020-01-01T05:00:00+01:00     30.14     30.14         25.00         25.00
6   2020-01-01T06:00:00+01:00     30.17     30.17         24.00         24.00
7   2020-01-01T07:00:00+01:00     30.00     30.00         24.00         24.00
8   2020-01-01T08:00:00+01:00     30.63     30.63         24.00         24.00
9   2020-01-01T09:00:00+01:00     30.59     30.59         25.00         25.00
10  2020-01-01T10:00:00+01:00     30.27     30.27         25.00         25.00
11  2020-01-01T11:00:00+01:00     30.34     30.34         25.00         25.00
12  2020-01-01T12:00:00+01:00     30.59     30.59         30.59         30.59
13  2020-01-01T13:00:00+01:00     30.04     30.04         30.04         30.04
14  2020-01-01T14:00:00+01:00     30.60     30.60         30.60         30.60
15  2020-01-01T15:00:00+01:00     31.09     31.09         31.09         31.09
16  2020-01-01T16:00:00+01:00     31.53     31.53         31.53         31.53
17  2020-01-01T17:00:00+01:00     31.78     31.78         33.50         33.50
18  2020-01-01T18:00:00+01:00     31.64     31.64         33.50         33.50
19  2020-01-01T19:00:00+01:00     31.44     31.44         31.44         31.44
20  2020-01-01T20:00:00+01:00     31.35     31.35         31.35         31.35
21  2020-01-01T21:00:00+01:00     31.07     31.07         31.07         31.07
22  2020-01-01T22:00:00+01:00     30.96     30.96         25.00         25.00
23  2020-01-01T23:00:00+01:00     30.61     30.61         21.00         21.00
24  2020-01-02T00:00:00+01:00     30.78     30.78         20.00         20.00
25  2020-01-02T01:00:00+01:00     30.64     30.64         20.00         20.00
26  2020-01-02T02:00:00+01:00     30.43     30.43         20.00         20.00
27  2020-01-02T03:00:00+01:00     28.79     28.79         23.00         23.00
28  2020-01-02T04:00:00+01:00     28.42     28.42         22.73         22.73
29  2020-01-02T05:00:00+01:00     28.75     28.75         23.00         23.00
30  2020-01-02T06:00:00+01:00     33.38     34.16         22.50         22.50
31  2020-01-02T07:00:00+01:00     31.79     42.07         22.28         22.28
32  2020-01-02T08:00:00+01:00     31.83     44.89         22.50         22.50
33  2020-01-02T09:00:00+01:00     31.74     45.26         23.00         23.00
34  2020-01-02T10:00:00+01:00     31.63     45.57         24.00         24.00
35  2020-01-02T11:00:00+01:00     31.32     45.09         25.00         25.00
36  2020-01-02T12:00:00+01:00     31.07     45.16         25.00         25.00
37  2020-01-02T13:00:00+01:00     31.06     44.90         25.00         25.00
38  2020-01-02T14:00:00+01:00     31.07     44.06         26.00         26.00
39  2020-01-02T15:00:00+01:00     31.26     44.84         26.00         26.00
40  2020-01-02T16:00:00+01:00     31.41     44.40         27.50         27.50
41  2020-01-02T17:00:00+01:00     31.40     46.05         26.00         46.05
42  2020-01-02T18:00:00+01:00     31.10     46.72         26.00         26.00
43  2020-01-02T19:00:00+01:00     30.75     45.26         25.32         25.32
44  2020-01-02T20:00:00+01:00     30.47     39.32         20.25         20.25
45  2020-01-02T21:00:00+01:00     30.10     30.10         16.50         16.50
46  2020-01-02T22:00:00+01:00     29.71     29.71         16.50         16.50
47  2020-01-02T23:00:00+01:00     24.99     24.99         15.00         15.00
48  2020-01-03T00:00:00+01:00     18.93     18.93         15.00         15.00
49  2020-01-03T01:00:00+01:00      9.98      9.98          9.98          9.98
```

I want to generate a separate series of values in which the maximum difference of each day's values are in. Preferably able to choose of which columns to include.

Therefore, the first value in the series should be 12.5, since the largest and lowest values of the first day are 33.5 and 21.00, respectively.

Expected outcome:

```
       Day          Max diff
0   2020-01-01       12.50
1   2020-01-02       31.72
```

So far, I've tried this - but this gives me a rolling, 24-hour interval, crossing days, which is what I try to avoid:

```
cols = ['Spot DK1','Spot DK2','Ubalance DK1','Ubalance DK2']
N = 24

battery['dif'] = (battery[cols].stack(dropna=False)
                     .rolling(len(cols) * N)
                     .agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
                     .groupby(level=0)
                     .max())
```

Comment: @jezrael I've edited question to include the code I've tried to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is aggregate minimal and maximal values per days, so possible get `max` and `min` by `max` and `min` levels in `df1` and last subtract to new `df2`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

cols = ['Spot DK1','Spot DK2','Ubalance DK1','Ubalance DK2']

df1 = (df.set_index('Timestamp')[cols]
         .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level='Timestamp'))
         .agg(['min','max']))

s1 = df1.xs('max', level=1, axis=1).max(axis=1)
s2 = df1.xs('min', level=1, axis=1).min(axis=1)

df2 = s1.sub(s2).rename_axis('Day').reset_index(name='Max diff')
print (df2)
                        Day  Max diff
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00     13.00
1 2020-01-02 00:00:00+01:00     31.72
2 2020-01-03 00:00:00+01:00      8.95
```

Details:

```
print (df1)
                          Spot DK1        Spot DK2        Ubalance DK1        \
                               min    max      min    max          min   max   
Timestamp                                                                      
2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    30.00  33.42    30.00  33.42        21.00  34.0   
2020-01-02 00:00:00+01:00    24.99  33.38    24.99  46.72        15.00  27.5   
2020-01-03 00:00:00+01:00     9.98  18.93     9.98  18.93         9.98  15.0   

                          Ubalance DK2         
                                   min    max  
Timestamp                                      
2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00        21.00  34.00  
2020-01-02 00:00:00+01:00        15.00  46.05  
2020-01-03 00:00:00+01:00         9.98  15.00
```